# Is there something like jLinq for PHP?

Tags: php, database

I just came across [jLinq](http://hugoware.net/Projects/jlinq), a JS library to query data (e.g. arrays) in a similar fashion to that of a Relational DB, and it just occurred to me that a library to query data like this in PHP would be extremely handy to work with cached subsets of a RDBMS where the cache itself has no querying capabilities, such as APC or memcached.

I'm aware there's no magic behind the library and "querying" the data can technically be done with raw PHP, but it seems more natural to query data with a syntax like that of jLinq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several. Have a look at:

[PHPLinq](http://phplinq.codeplex.com/)

[LinqForPHP](http://linqforphp.codeplex.com/)

[Phinq](http://code.google.com/p/phinq/)

Comment: Interesting. Didn't know LINQ was a standard .NET component. Do you happen to know anything about these, how do they perform or what do their overhead look like?

Answer (score 2):

Look at Yii framework (PHP-based) - it have wery complex tools for working with data-bases.